# Javascript var inside a c# function inside Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to write a javascript function that calls an Dictionary value and than tries to split it on a ´_'. The problem is that the Key to get the value from Dictionary is in an Javascript var that is extracted from a dropdownlist. Is it possible to use an Javascript var inside an c# function inside Javascript?

the Code as it is now:

```
var Category = document.getElementById('Properties').value;
var Name = document.getElementById(Category).value;
Category = '@Model.Dictionary[Name].Split('_')[0]';
```

EDIT:

People are misinterpreting my problem, the .Split function does work but the Dictionary[Name] is giving me problems. if i enter

```
var Category = document.getElementById('Properties').value;
var Name = document.getElementById(Category).value;
Category = '@Model.Dictionary["Bicycle"].Split('_')[0]';
```

into the code it works perfectly, but I want to get the "Bicycle" part dynamically out of an DropDownList.

EDIT 2:

Okay I have decided that what I am over thinking the situation and that what I am trying to do needs alot more work than is needed, found a beter solutions, thanks for everybody that tried to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have avoided the issue completely by having the DropDownList have different values in Value and Text, doing this is can get the wanted input that used to be in the Dictionary out of the Value of the DropDownList without changing the Text.

Answer (score 1):

You're a bit mixed up between client and server side.  To interact with server side code like this, you'll need to either post to the server or write an AJAX callback to call a server method.

http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2008/10/mvc-framework-and-jquery-ajax-heaven.html

Comment: This seems to be a frequent problem with .NET devs. What gives?

Comment: @Diodeus: Part of the problem can be blamed on the ASP.NET page model, which does its best to hide the stateless nature of the web.

Comment: Web forms breaks peoples logical brains. Inline javascript, css and styling is rife and people assume it can go both ways. Although looking at his example it does look like he wants to assign a C# value to javascript which is possible but so ugly and horrible to maintain. I really wish you couldnt.

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible. All the server code runs before the page is sent to the browser, and all the client code runs after.

What you would have to do to use the dictionary in the client code is to create Javascript code from the server side, that recreates the dictionary on the client side.

If that's not possible, you would have to make an AJAX call to the server.